# Postfix doesn't send emails to Gmail, Outlook. Multiple domains and Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, email, smtp, postfix-mta, spf

**The problem**: None of the emails sent trough any of the 8 Wordpress installations on the VPS trough contact form are being received by gmail. Please help, I'm a begginer. Didn't found simple tutorial online that works. But here is what happens:

1. Tried to host my own VPS server (Debian9)
2. Made virtual hosts and added 8 domain names
3. Connected them all to Cloudflare (to increase speed)
4. Added free Zoho accounts to the DNS records MX/SPF (to have mails like mymail@mysite.com)
   `v=spf1 include:zoho.com ~all` and `_domainkey`
5. Installed Postfix, configured it with the idea that I'll be able to send from Wordpress contact forms and password reset emails
6. Wrote to my VPS provider. He says:

> Since you are sending emails from www-data@servername.cloud the SPF check fails, because we do not allow sending emails with our domain.

EMAIL ERROR LOG:

```
Aug  6 02:30:44 2n5z postfix/smtp[1050]: C739381595: to=<somemeail@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4010:c08::1a]:25, delay=0.42, delays=0/0.01/0.08/0.33, dsn=5.7.26, status=bounced (host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4010:c08::1a] said: 550-5.7.26 This message does not have authentication information or fails to 550-5.7.26 pass authentication checks. To best protect our users from spam, the 550-5.7.26 message has been blocked. Please visit 550-5.7.26  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication for more 550 5.7.26 information. z2si1913276ljj.406 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command))
```

Full log here: https://pastebin.com/6wwepVrM
Otherwise it says it's spam.

Comment: Please don't ever suggest me using third party services, SMTP wordpress plugins and so on. That's not what I'm asking for. I'm willing to donate to the best answer because I have this problem since January this year.

Comment: You are trying to `open relay` email to Gmail. That is not possible. You need to authenticate with Gmail first and have an account. Google search for `Postfix Gmail Relay`. https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/configure-postfix-to-send-mail-using-gmail-and-google-apps-on-debian-or-ubuntu/ Unless you have some real experience setting up email servers, you have a `BIG` challenge ahead of you. Use a third pay service. Think SPF, DKIM, DMARC, Reverse DNS on top of configuring Postfix. Otherwise, your emails will just go to SPAM or be refused/rejected/dropped.